# Passing a parameter to visualforce in lightning experience

Tags: visualforce, lightning, navigation

We have a Visualforce page in Lightning Experience and we are using an `apex:outputLink` to pass a parameter to the same page, so that we can edit an item on the page.

VF Page 'MySetup' Snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doNav()
    {
        sforce.one.navigateToURL('', false);
    }
</script>
<apex:outputLink onclick="doNav" >Edit
  <apex:param value="{!myEditId}" name="editId" />
</apex:outputLink>
```

Controller:

```
public MySetupController() {
    if (ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().containsKey('editId')) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

In a namespaced scratch org this functions correctly and the controller finds a match when the navigation occurs, but as soon as we use this code within a managed package the following error occurs:

> Page MySetup does not exist

It appears that the managed package can not find the page, even though it is just navigating to the current page.

We have tried using the `apex:outputLink` value attribute instead of an `onclick` event, but the parameter is not passed.

We have also tried updating the `navigateToURL` reference to the direct page reference in lighting (`/lightning/n/mynamespace__MySetup`) but this also fails.

Is there an alternative approach we can take here?